# Visual Studio 2010 - Cannot open source file <QtGui/QApplication>

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt

I'm under Visual Studio 2010 and have installed `qt-vs-addin-1.1.11-opensource.exe` and `qt-win-opensource-4.8.4-vs2010.exe`. There is `Qt` in my VS menu. When I tried to start `Qt4 project->Qt Application` and error seemed to occur.

Here is the default code generated automatically:

```
#include "sp_qt.h"
#include <QtGui/QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    SP_Qt w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Error: `Cannot open include file QtGui/QApplication`

It seems VS cannot find the header.I know this should be simple, I have tried to modify environment variables `PATH` and `QTDIR` but doesn't seem to work(I added `C:\Qt\4.8.4\bin` to `PATH` and `C:\Qt` to `QTDIR`).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to make sure the path to the QT header files are in the project settings. Open up the project settings and go into "Configuration Properties-> C/C++ -> General" and add the path in "Additional Include Directories.

You can access the project properties by either right clicking on the project and selecting "Properties" or selecting the "Project" menu and selecting "Properties".

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Which directory should I include in 'additional include directories'?

Comment: It should be you include folder from the installation QT directory.

exemple: C:\Qt\Qt5.3.1\5.3\msvc2010_opengl\include

Answer (score 7):

I found a another solution for this situation.

If you have **QT addin** in **VS** you can add your library with;

Right Click to Project -> Qt Project Settings -> Qt Modules

add Core, GUI, Multimedia, Network,Script etc.