# Visual Studio / Qt - Cannot open source file "QApplication"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt

I have **VS 2017**, **qt-opensource-windows-x86-msvc2015_64-5.8.0**, **qt-vsaddin-msvc2017-2.6.0-rev.07**.

https://api-2d3d-cad.com/c-qt/ to setup.

Qt VS Tools widget is present, can make Qt Console Application.

But:

```
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QLabel>

Cannot open source file "QApplication"
Cannot open source file "QLabel"
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16682269/10226040 - tried, not working.

Thx.

Comment: Do you use "Qt VS Tools" ? and if true, check compatibility between tool and vs.

Comment: Yes. In Qt VS Tools -> Qt options -> Qt versions I have msvc2015_64 as my complier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use Qt libs in Visual studio do next steps! This answer is based on `Visual studio 2017`! on other versions, differences are only on menus or settings interfaces!

1. Install `Qt Vs Tools`, check its version compatibility with Visual studio
2. Go Qt VS Tools -> Qt Options menu
   [image]
3. In `Qt Versions` tab, add installed Qt libs with its path and name, and set default Qt/Win version
4. Check `Qt Default Settings` tab, it seems as below
   [image]
5. On `Solution Explorer` view, open project properties, go `Qt Project Settings` and on `Qt Modules` tab set required modules such as `Core`.
   [image]
   You can see other settings in tabs `Qt Meta-Object Compiler` to change `moc` file generation settings, `Qt User Interface Compiler` to change `form` and `ui` compilation settings.
6. If you have any form file, i.e. `*.ui` file, you can get its properties and check followings are set properly by default! or modify them as you need!

[image]
[image]

7. Go C/C++ Tab, `General`, check `Additional Include Directories` stared items must be exist!
   [image]

Comment: Thank you! Haven't tried your answer, but the problem in my case is that if you set xxx/include folder in "Additional Include Folders" VS doesn't do recursive search in all the sub directories.

Comment: Do not set it! build your project from begin properly, It will be set by default!

Comment: Hm, I don't have Qt project settings in 5 step like you do

Comment: Visual studio has "Quick launch box" on top of it! find it or press "Ctrl+q" and type "Qt Project Settings"

Comment: Sorry for being dumb, but no result. Maybe it is because I am using msvc2015 with VS 2017...because you are using 2017

Comment: May be! So check your IDE you find solution